# execute if command is non-empty

Tags: bash

```
sudo kill $(ps aux | grep '[p]ostgres'|awk '{print $2}')
```

For above command, I want it to execute only if

```
$(ps aux | grep '[p]ostgres'|awk '{print $2}')
```

is non-empty, otherwise it will throw me error like this

[image]

How should I achieve this?

Comment: A better approach might be to replace the whole pipeline with `pkill -f` e.g. `sudo pkill -f postgres`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) properly mentioned in the [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998859/execute-if-command-is-non-empty#comment1614216_998859) that for your specific purpose, it's better to use `pkill -f` , since filtering output of `ps` via `grep` has downside of `grep` command itself appearing  on the `ps` list.  By contrast, ,`pkill` doeesn't do that and performs cleanly.

As for *general* case where you'd want to run any command if a positional parameter to it is blank, there's two ways to approach it. One, save to variable and check if variable is not empty:

```
var=$(ps aux | grep '[p]ostgres'|awk '{print $2}')
if ! [ "x$var" = "x"  ]; then
    sudo kill "$var"
fi
```

The other way is via `xargs` and `--no-run-if-empty` (or short-hand `-r`):

```
ps aux | grep '[p]ostgres'|awk '{print $2}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill
```

Comment: Thanks, is it the same if I use `if [ -n $var ] then` or `if [ "$var" != "" ] then` in the condition?

Comment: @william007 Effectively, yes - those are equivalent in result but logically different; one is checking variable contents, the other compares strings. Beware of `[ ! "$var" = "" ]`, which may look same but if you work in different shells there are cases where that test might not work properly (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416618/85039) ).  The `[ -n "$var" ]` is OK, and remember to quote variables there.

Comment: Also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400895/85039).  There's unfortunately lots of corner cases when it comes to shell scripting :)  The syntax I use here, should be safe and more or less portable.